# Pintar fila completa de una grilla

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

estoy aquí para consultar lo siguiente, utilizo esto para pintar en la grilla según la condición que asigne, pero estoy solamente pintando esa celda, quisiera pintar la fila completa, estuve buscando información pero la verdad no encontré si hay  me pudiera dar una mano se lo agradecería, Saludos.

[image: PintarSegunLaCondición]

[image: imagen]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad `Rows` del `gridview`para seleccionar la fila completa en lugar de columna por columna. Muestro una versión simplificada de un método que utilizo para tal motivo:

```
protected void PintarGrid(GridView grid, int fila)
{
     grid.Rows[fila].BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

> Actualización

Puedes recorrer fila por fila el grid, y consultar para cada fila si la columna del stock está en 0, así:

```
protected void PintarGrid(GridView grid, int indiceColumna)
        {
            for (int indiceFila = 0; indiceFila < grid.Rows.Count; indiceFila++)
            {
                TableCell campo = grid.Rows[indiceFila].Cells[indiceColumna];
                if (campo.Text.Equals("0"))
                {
                    grid.Rows[indiceFila].BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: bien, ahora en el caso de Fila, debería asignar a cada fila que cumple con esa condición, que pondría en [fila] ??

Comment: ¿Que condición quieres verificar? No sé si quieres pintar entonces la columna completa o la fila completa. Porque en el código que muestras preguntas si la columna se llama "Stock". En ese caso todas las filas tendrían dicha columna y por lo tanto se pintarían todas las filas.

Comment: Acabo de subir una imagen de como está en la publicacion actual, yo ahora quiero que en los elementos de la grilla que tengan el campo stock en 0 se pinte la fila completa, se entiende?

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, puedes ver que modifiqué el método para que consulta en cada fila la condición dada.

Comment: bien, lo entiendo, ahora el TableCell que tipo de dato es? y en el int indiceColumna a que te referis? por que debo buscar por un string osea el nombre de esa columna.